# Deserialize Multidimensional Array from JSON

Tags: json, spring-boot, kotlin, jackson

I need help deserializing from a JSON string the following matrix

```
[[0,241680,1504951,608814],[242011,0,1422310,526173],[1509111,1427078,0,929523],[607952,525919,922264,0]]
```

The problem is that I have no idea what data structure to use in Kotlin to do this.

Any ideas?

So far, i've tried the following:

```
    private fun createMatrix(json: String, mapper: ObjectMapper): List<List<Long>> {
        val typeFactory = mapper.typeFactory
        return mapper.readValue(json, typeFactory.constructCollectionType(List::class.java, IntArray::class.java))
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Jackson allows you to specify Type references much nicer as anomymous objects

```
val mapper = ObjectMapper()
    .registerModule(KotlinModule())

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val list = testList("[[0,241680,1504951,608814],[242011,0,1422310,526173],[1509111,1427078,0,929523],[607952,525919,922264,0]]")
    val array = testArray("[[0,241680,1504951,608814],[242011,0,1422310,526173],[1509111,1427078,0,929523],[607952,525919,922264,0]]")
    println(list)
    println(array)
}

fun testList(text: String): List<List<Int>> {
    return mapper.readValue(text, object : TypeReference<List<List<Int>>>() {} )
}

fun testArray(text: String): Array<Array<Int>> {
    return mapper.readValue(text, object : TypeReference<Array<Array<Int>>>() {} )
}
```